# Gerar número aleatório com regra de repetição

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Preciso de um comando SQL que gere um número aleatório entre 1 e 11, e que para o número 1 seja gerado com mais frequência do que os outros.

Atualmente uso o seguinte comando:

```
FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 11))
```

Ele esta em um comando WHERE do SQL, exemplo:

```
WHERE numero < FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 11))
```

Esse WHERE esta em um comando SQL, que é executada em uma procedure e que roda a cada segundo, ou seja, a cada segundo é gerado um número diferente.

O problema é que esse comando ele gera os número aleatoriamente, sem a regra do número 1 com mais frequência.

Como posso alterar esse comando para que ele gere os números aleatoriamente sendo que para o número 1 seja gerado com mais frequência?

Comment: Com que frequência você quer que o número 1 se repita?

Comment: @FelipeMarinho Poderia ser 2 vezes seguida, ou a cada dois números diferentes gerados.

Comment: Tente algo como    FLOOR(1 + (POWER(RAND(),2) * 11))

Comment: @Motta Até funcionou, mas não gerou o número 1 com muita frequência não. Ele apareceu mais vezes, mas não como preciso. Ele aparece a cada 5 ou 6 números gerados..

Comment: Aumente o exponte para 3 por exemplo , outra solução e criar uma function , monte um array com a frequência que você quer e sorteie a posição deste array , algo como 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 20 posições sendo o 1 frequente 50% das vezes

Comment: @Motta Não entendo muito de SQL, quem montou essa proc para mim foi outra pessoa que não tenho mais contato. Como seria esse array? E no caso do expoente, é aquele número 2 q vc colocou ali?

Comment: FLOOR(1 + (POWER(RAND(),3) * 11)) mudando este expoente até ajustar o viés que se precisa. Só para você entender o POWER eleva um número à uma potência para valores entre 0 e 1 elevar a um número maior que 1 "achata" por assim dizer o mesmo , 0,5^2 = 0,25 ,  por exemplo , isto torna os valores mais baixos mais frequentes na amostragem, simulando . aqui com 3 1 ficou com 45% das ocorrências